# Remove global scopes while applying another scope in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, scope, laravel-9, php-8.1

In my multi-tenant application, Institutions can only see the Assignments they create. Assignments become templates if they are marked as `is_template`. If a template is marked as `is_shared` then all institutions should be able to see it.

To achieve the multi-tenancy part, I have a global `InstitutionScope` that works as expected:

```
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where($model->getTable() . '.institution_id', auth()->user()->institution_id);
    }
```

I also have a local `not_template` scope on the Assignment model, which again works well:

```
    static::addGlobalScope('not_template', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('is_template', '=', false);
    });
```

I'm now trying to create the scope for the Template model, which extends the Assignment model. This is what I have so far:

```
    static::addGlobalScope('template', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->withoutGlobalScopes([InstitutionScope::class, 'not_template'])
        ->where('is_shared', '=', true)
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->where('institution_id', auth()->user()->institution_id)
            ->where('is_template', true);
        });
    });
```

However, this scope does not work - specifically, it does not remove the other two scopes, so the sql query generated to get all templates is

`select * from "assignments" where "assignments"."institution_id" = ? and ("is_shared" = ? or ("institution_id" = ? and "is_template" = ?))`

Is there a way of removing other scopes when applying a global scope to a model?

---

Edit to add - the InsitutionScope is applied to the Assignments by a BelongsToInstitution trait, which is the inherited by the extended Template model

Comment: As a temporary solution, I've modified the `BelongsToInstitution` trait to conditionally apply the multi-tenant restriction (`if (static::class != Template::class)`), but holding out for something that feels a bit less hacky

Comment: btw, `withoutGlobalScopes` only takes 1 argument: `public function withoutGlobalScopes(array $scopes = null)`

Comment: @lagbox ah, good spot- fixed the typo in the post